# Choose schema of PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, schema

I have created simple trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emplacement_libre() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$


DECLARE

i int;
curseur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM beta2.astres a
    INNER JOIN beta2.planetes p ON a.id = p.astre_id 
    WHERE a.galaxie = NEW.galaxie AND
    a.ss = NEW.ss AND
    a.position = NEW.position;

BEGIN

OPEN curseur;   

LOOP
    FETCH curseur INTO i;

    IF i>0 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'la planète est déjà occupée';
    END IF;

    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

END LOOP;

CLOSE curseur;

RETURN NEW;

END;


$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER emplacement_libre
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON beta2.astres
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE emplacement_libre();
```

In PostgreSQL doc, it is written about the name of a trigger :

> The name to give the new trigger. This must be distinct from the name of any other trigger for the same table. The name cannot be schema-qualified — **the trigger inherits the schema of its table**. For a constraint trigger, this is also the name to use when modifying the trigger's behavior using SET CONSTRAINTS.

So I expected my trigger to get schema `beta2` because I use it in my `CREATE TRIGGER` request but it's not the case, my trigger is created inside default `public` schema...why ?

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: My problem was just I did not call procedure beta2.emplacement_libre() but only emplacement_libre(). Now problem is solved ty

Comment: I suppose to close the question then.

Comment: Agreed we should close it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is over the schema the trigger exists in vs the `search_path` of the trigger, i.e. the schema the function you call is.

The trigger is stored in the same schema as the table.  However the search path for the procedure is handled at creation time based on your current `search_path` settings.  So if you want to call a function in a specific schema, you probably want to call by the schema-qualified name.